# Automatically set mysql autoincrement to min value

Tags: mysql, reset, auto-increment

i just wondered, if there is an elegant way of automatically resetting the autoincrement of a mysql table to the lowest value according to the present content.

example:

mytable:

```
1  content of row 1
2  content of row 2
3  content of row 3
4  content of row 4
5  content of row 5
```

now the autoincrement will be at 6

but before i insert new contents, i delete row 3,4 and 5. the content would look like this:

```
1  content of row 1
2  content of row 2
```

the autoincrement would still be at 6.

and this is the issue.

i would like the autoincrement to be at 3, because it is the lowest possible value according to the inserted IDs.

the would prevent extremely large numbers, if the autoincrement would grow "infinitely" and get out of range of a 12 digits long integer.

thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I provided answer below, but i should comment that in most cases, the actual value of the automincrement field is meaningless, so trying to guarantee and continuous order from 1 to whatever the highest value is isn't necessary.  You can also feel free to use a BIGINT data type which allow values up to `18446744073709551615`.  I am guessing that should suffice for most use cases. So your concern about growing to infinity should not be a factor in how you design your app to work.

Comment: Wait what? My document with id=3 has _totally_ changed? Who did that, what happened to it? Mayhem! `</confused user>` (i.e.: don't recycle id's if you can avoid it)

Comment: Nice comment by @Wrikken - This is another strong point in why in in most tables with an autoincrementing primary key, you should never do deletes.  If you need to "delete" or deactivate an item you can typically do this easily by adding a TINYINT "deleted" column with a value of 0 or 1 to indicate whether the item should be considered available for use.

Comment: yes, the BIGINT is an option, but would this affect the database performance because of increased space and comparing large numbers? @ wrikken: i would never advise someone to hardcode fixed ids. of course you would then have different/wrong relations. @ mike brant: you would rather let the table grow und decrease the performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on your storage engine,

For MyISAM and for InnoDB on MySQL 5.6+, you can set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for the table to say `1`. That value will automatically be increased to the maximum current value + 1. Do that like this.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

For InnoDB on MySQL < 5.6, this will not work and you will need to do this manually like this:

```
SELECT MAX(autoincrement_field) + 1 FROM table_name INTO @maxautoinc;
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = @maxautoinc;
```

Note in that last case, the two queries will need to be run with the same database connection.

Comment: This will work, but WHY should I do this? Because the database tables looks better, if someone take a look at the IDs?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I would agree with your sentiment.  Typically when one uses autoincrement fields they really don't care what the actual autoincrement values are, just that they are guaranteed to be unique and ascending based on insert order.

Comment: @MikeBrant With auto-generated values... I don't even believe their order should matter. Use timestamps if you need a history is what I was taught.

Comment: thanks, i think a modification like this: ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(autoincrement_field) + 1 FROM table_name); should do the work.

Comment: One-shot update (select and alter) does not work.
First ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; works also for InnoDB.

Comment: @Xdg Glad to see your comment. I have updated this old answer to reflect being able to use single `ALTER TABLE` statement for InnoDB on MySQL 5.6+

Answer (score 1):

Reset Auto Increment IDs.

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/3042-reset-auto-increment-ids

update all auto increment columns in a database to the smallest possible value based on current values in the databases. We needed to do this after cleaning out a database.

Use a Prepared Statement within a Stored Procedure:

```
drop PROCEDURE if exists reset_autoincrement;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE reset_autoincrement (IN schemaName varchar(255))
 BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE o_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE o_table VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE extra LIKE '%auto_increment%' and table_schema=schemaName;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
     FETCH cur1 INTO o_name, o_table;

     IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;

  set @qry1 = concat('SELECT MAX(`',o_name,'`) + 1 as autoincrement FROM `',o_table,'` INTO @ai'); 
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @qry1;
  EXECUTE stmt1;

  IF @ai IS NOT NULL THEN
      SELECT  o_name, o_table;
   select @qry1;
   select @ai;
   set @qry2 = concat('ALTER TABLE `',o_table,'` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @ai);
   select @qry2;
   PREPARE stmt2 FROM @qry2;
   EXECUTE stmt2;
  END IF;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
 END //
DELIMITER ;


call reset_autoincrement('my_schema_name');
```